# How to create static lib for MAC OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mountain-lion

how can i compile the Linux source code for MAC OSX 10.6,7 & 8 . below the points are listed

1:I have to create native code for MAC separately ?
2:How can i create Linux code in to static library for MAC OSX  ?

please any one suggest me right solution. 
Is there a way to have a project on Xcode that ultimately produces the same kind of library? How?

Comment: When you say "Linux code", what do you mean?  If the code is POSIX-compliant then it will compile without modification (probably), otherwise it will most likely take only minor modification to compile under OSX.

Comment: Linux code means ..i have an application which is runing on linux os ...now i need to develop it on MAC OS.how can i do this ..?

Comment: Tell us what doesn't work.

Comment: i have some linux code library 'v4L2loopback module' and gudev library ,now both library i have to use for MAC OSX . give me some idea

Comment: My code is not POSIX- compliant .so what type of miner change i have to do.